# Ruby on Rails: Cannot Move URL for Contact Form Without Getting NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, contact-form, nomethoderror, mail-form

I am new to rails and I am having trouble moving a contact form from "/contacts" to "/contact". Simple, I know!

I followed the following guide, and got everything working: 
https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/

However, I cannot seem to do something as simple as change the URL without getting an error. As I'm learning, this seemed like something I should be able to do... I made the following changes:

1) Changed routes.rb:

```
match '/contacts', to: 'contacts#new', via: 'get'
resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
```

Became

```
match '/contact', to: 'contact#new', via: 'get'
resources "contact", only: [:new, :create]
```

2) 
Renamed "app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb" to "app/controllers/contact_controller.rb"

3) 
Updated and changed the first line of "contact_controller.rb":

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
```

Became

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
```

4) 
Moved the views from "app/views/contacts/" to "app/views/contact/"

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Contact#new
undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0xa0e4500>:0xa0efb28>
Did you mean?  contact_path
```

Thinking there is a "contacts_path" somewhere, I did a search in the entire project and no "contacts" exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Ruby 2.3.3
Rails 5.0.1

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: @radubogdan Yes. I have tried that a few times. The line it highlights is this one: `<%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default path for a `form_for @object` when the object is not persisted (new record) is always `objects_path`.  You'll have to explicitly state the url, something like...

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact, as: :contact, url: '/contact', html: { class: "new_contact", id: "new_contact" } do |f| %>
```

BUT this is going to mess up the form for your existing contacts when you try to edit them.

You'll have to do an `<% if @contact.new_record? %>` and `<% else %>` and `<% end %>` to handle the two different URLs required.

So the best recommendation is really follow the convention!  Use plurals for the controller, set the route back to the way it was.

Unless you have a compelling reason to violate the "convention over configuration" rule, you shouldn't.

The docs explain the default URLs used.  https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: This did the trick! And thank you for the information on `form_for @object`, and "convention over configuration." This is all new, so I very much appreciate it! I have voted up the answer... Just don't have enough reputation yet. :)

Comment: Glad I could help!  Although you may not be able to "vote up" the answer yet, you should have an option to "accept" the answer... the option is immediately to the left of my answer. That would be great if you could do that.

Comment: Done! Thank you!